# JavaScript: How can I stop SetTimout reloading my page?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function that sets `display=none` on a table row.  At the end of my function I want to set a timeout to hide the next table row after a few milliseconds.

I have a problem though.  When the timeout expires, the page is reloaded (undoing the effects of my function and and scrolling to page top).  This even happens if I use an empty timeout:  `window.SetTimeout(function () { ; }, 1000);` How can I stop this happening?

I am using recent Chromium.

Comment: More code would be nice.

Comment: setTimeout does not reload the page on its own ...

Comment: I was hoping this would be easily answered without too much detail.  I'll condense my for easy posting, brb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is somewhere else, disregarding the obvious error that you cased `SetTimeout` wrong ( it should be `setTimeout` ).

There is nothing in your code that should refresh the page.

**Edit:**

Just thought of something, since you cased `SetTimeout` wrong, maybe your click handler doesn't finish as it should, thus letting the link "pass through" and load the page.

**Edit2:**

Huh, thats not the case....

http://jsfiddle.net/eGhQM/6/

**Edit3:**

...and maybe it is(x-something error on fiddle though)
http://jsfiddle.net/eGhQM/9/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the question, but you can use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) if you store the timeout you set. That is to say:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  alert('Hello, world!');
}, 1000);

...
clearTimeout(timeout); // destroys the timeout, preventing it from occurring
                       // (assuming you call this before the time expires)
```